# Is there any version problem in Silverlight 3 beta?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-toolkit

I have deployed website using silverlight 3.0.40307.0. It is working perfectly in Local IIS. But when client will installs the newer version of silverlight like 3.0.40626 or higher, It wan't be able to view website.

How to get silverlight 3.0.40307 (old version of 3.0 beta)?

What is the possible solution to deploy silverlight website on IIS?

What silverlight component should be installed on server to view silverlight application on browser?

Can we install silverlight TOOL without VS2008+SP1? if yes, then how?

Comment: Why would you want to release an application using the Beta version? Why not convert your app to the full release?

Answer (score 3):

You need to upgrade your version of Silverlight to the released version. You can't expect users to run beta software because you would be forcing them to use software that is known to contain defects.

You need to download the latest version of the SDK and templates from [here](http://silverlight.net/GetStarted/).

Answer (score 0):

Clients need only the Silverlight runtime plugin for their browser. There's no way you can enforce the client to install the SL 3 Beta version of the plugin you want; and even if you do, there's no (easy) way to prevent it from self-updating to the RTM version. Not only that, but asking clients to install a Beta version of a released product is a security threat for them.

There's no official way to get the SL 3 Beta runtime installer.

An SL app is a client-side code; on the server side you only need standard IIS that serves HTML with an  tag and the .xap file for the SL application.

There are no SL components required to be installed on the server for the client to run the SL app.

You can't install the Silverlight Visual Studio Tools without VS2008 SP1 - as their name suggests, the tools are intended to integrate with VS. However, you can install the SL SDK and build SL applications without having VS2008 SP1. (Alternatively, you could use MonoDevelop/Mono/Moonlight to develop SL applications)

Comment: You can use Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition to write to the Silverlight 3.0 full version, as the Silverlight tools are supported here (I use this for my Silverlight Development!).

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I just consider VWD 2008 Express to be just another VS2008 SKU. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have deployed your silverlight app that is compiled with Silverlight version 3.0.4.0307.0(i.e. Silverlight Beta), your app may work perfectly for the users with Silverlight 3(RTM).

However, if those visitors come across your silverlight app who doesn't have Silverlight installed at all(or maybe lower than Silverlight 3 Beta), they will be prompted to download Silverlight to view your app.

Once they wish to download Silverlight runtime by clicking on the "Get Silverlight" button, visitors will be redirected to Silverlight download location, and the most important part is

**They will get a message explaining that this app is made with Beta version of the Silverlight. 
So this may hamper thier experience and impression about your silverlight app and because of this very few people can get to your app correctly **

It is my suggestion that you try to compile your project with Silverlight 3 as early as possible .

Regarding 2nd question **What is the possible solution to deploy silverlight website on IIS?**

Here is the Answer : You'll need to register the MIME types for xap on your server.